# AUCTeX: TeX-PDF-from-DVI is always "Dvips" and file is compiled to DVI instead of PDF

Tags: pdf, emacs, auctex, dvi

I have a weird behavior of the `TeX-PDF-from-DVI` variable from AUCTeX: it keeps being set to "Dvips", and Emacs keeps calling latex instead of pdflatex.

I start with a minimal file `test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

I also have with a minimal `.emacs` file.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacs.d/lisp")

(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
```

When I open `test.tex` in Emacs, the value of variable `TeX-PDF-mode` is `t`, and the value of `TeX-PDF-from-DVI` is `nil`. This is what I want. However, when I add the line `\usepackage[pdftex]{geometry}` as line 2, save the file, restart Emacs and reload the file, the value of `TeX-PDF-from-DVI` becomes "Dvips". Correspondingly, when I type <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>, the file is compiled to DVI rather than PDF.

After that, I tried customizing variable `TeX-PDF-from-DVI` to "No DVI to PDF conversion". This adds

```
(custom-set-variables
...
 '(TeX-PDF-from-DVI nil)
 ...
```

to `.emacs`, as expected, but it does not change the value of `TeX-PDF-from-DVI` in the `test.tex` buffer, which is still "Dvips". When I restart Emacs and load `test.tex`, the value of `TeX-PDF-from-DVI` is still "Dvips". Even adding the line `%%% TeX-PDF-from-DVI: nil` at the end of the file in the Local Variables section does not help: after reloading the file the value is still "Dvips".

I am not sure how it started. For a long time I only used pdflatex, and Emacs never compiled to DVI. Then I worked with a file that used PSTricks, and Emacs recognized that it needs to compile to PS through DVI. But now I can't restore the original behavior. I have to run `(setq TeX-PDF-from-DVI nil)` or select Command | TeXing Options | PDF from DVI | Compile directly to PDF every time I start Emacs.

My questions are the following.

1. How can I make compiling to PDF the default behavior, while preferably retaining parsing the file looking for content that does need to be compiled through DVI?
2. What sets `TeX-PDF-from-DVI` besides customization (which apparent does not work)?

Comment: I have no idea regarding your emacs problem, but you don't need the pdftex option `\usepackage[pdftex]{geometry}`,  simply `\usepackage{geometry}` is quite enough.

Comment: Which AUCTeX version do you use?  Can you please install the latest version from ELPA with `M-x list-packages RET`, mark the auctex package for installation with `i`, and hit `x` to execute the installation procedure, restart Emacs and try it again?  After the restart, also check your installation with `M-x list-load-path-shadows RET` and check if you have leftovers.

Comment: @Arash Esbati, I have Emacs 26.3 and AUCTeX 13.0.13. Just in case, I deleted AUCTeX and reinstalled it using `list-packages`. `list-load-path-shadows` shows "`/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/latex-cjk-thai/thai-word` hides `/usr/share/emacs/26.3/lisp/language/thai-word`". The value of `TeX-PDF-from-DVI` did not change: it is still "Dvips".

Answer (score 1):

I think I understood the problem. A short answer is that Emacs confused the local style file `auto/geometry.el` produced by editing an unrelated file `geometry.tex` with a style file corresponding to the package `geometry.sty`.

Before I worked with `test.tex`, I edited and compiled `geometry.tex` in the same directory. Emacs created the local style file `auto/geometry.el`. Since `geometry.tex` used PSTricks, `auto/geometry.el` contained the instruction `(TeX-run-style-hooks "latex2e" ... "pstricks" ...)`. In turn, the PSTricks style hook contained in `pstricks.el` reasonably assigns "Dvips" to `TeX-PDF-from-DVI`. The *Messages* buffer says that after opening `test.tex`, Emacs loaded a global style file `~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.0.13/style/geometry.elc` for the geometry package, and then it loaded `auto/geometry.el` as a local style file for that package. That's why `TeX-PDF-from-DVI` ended up with the value "Dvips".

This shows that it is dangerous to give your file the same name as one of the packages loaded by some file in the same project. I guess the AUCTeX manual warns about this in section 5.5: "Please note that all matching files found in `TeX-style-path` are loaded, and all hooks defined in the files will be executed". Still, it may make sense to introduce a difference between style files for LaTeX packages and style files for local files.